# What is the best php optimization between these two chunks?

Tags: php, function, variables, optimization

My question is about to make some laugh but I like keeping things clean and clear when I code, here's my question 'what is the best between both the chunks ?' :

```
$placeholders['createtime'] = is_null($Article->get_createtime())
                                ? 'NOW()'
                                : $Article->get_createtime();
```

or

```
$createTime = $Article->get_createtime();
$placeholders['createtime'] = is_null($createTime) ? 'NOW()' : $createTime;
```

I would tend to say the second one is better regarding procedural performances but as I barely know about how php manages variables into memory and functions' calls I decided to ask.

I know it also depends on the complexity of the function `get_createtime()` and if the function is long to process it is better to store the result in the memory, but my question stars basic getters with just a return instruction inside.

Comment: I'd say even thinking about this might be a case of **premature optimization**. If `get_createtime` is a "dumb" getter, the performance difference will most probably be negligible (you can benchmark though, to be sure). I'd prefer the second version, not because of performance, but because of *readability*.

Comment: I think the second one is better because it is more readable and self explaining. When i start to read your question the first chunk of code looks too messy so i just pass it and start to read the second one and almost immediately get it

Answer (score 0):

I think the first one is more performant than the second one because the second one requires to allocate and create a new variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not strictly checking against `null` then I suggest using example below where you get rid of `is_null()` call:

```
$placeholders['createtime'] = $Article->get_createtime()
                              ? $Article->get_createtime()
                              : now();
```

I would certainly not use second one because you're allocation system resources for `$createTime` which is unnecessary. However, if you don't care then you should use `$createTime = '';` to free up memory instead of `unset($createTime);`. Read up on [How PHP manages variables](https://entwickler.de/webandphp/how-php-manages-variables-125644.html) to see why. A bit long winded but very interesting read.

Comment: thanks a lot for the link, it looks nice, i'll read with a cup of coffee tomorrow morning because coffee rules!